# What gets passed to the mutate and modify?

Tags: r, if-statement, data-cleaning, purrr, mutate

I'm fairly new to R but not new to programming itself. I am using a simplified example of my code here. I have a dataframe that has three columns ( doc_id, tag_list, single_tag) all of which are characters.

```
df <- data.frame('doc_id' = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                 'tag_list' = c("tagA1,tagA2,tagA3", "tagB1,tabB2", "tagC3, tagC4", "tagD1,tagD3,tagD4"),
                 'single_tag' = c("tagA2", NA, "tagC", NA)
                 )
```

Here is what I've been doing:
If the value of single_tag is NA, I try to replace it with the value in tag_list.

```
df %>% mutate(single_tag = ifelse(is.na(single_tag), tag_list, single_tag))
```

This works as expected with the following output

```
  doc_id          tag_list        single_tag
1      A tagA1,tagA2,tagA3             tagA2
2      B       tagB1,tabB2       tagB1,tabB2
3      C      tagC3, tagC4              tagC
4      D tagD1,tagD3,tagD4 tagD1,tagD3,tagD4
```

Now I want to do the same thing again, but this time, I would like to replace the first value in tag_list if single_tag is NA (expected output below). Here's the code I try.

```
df %>% mutate(single_tag = ifelse(is.na(single_tag), str_split(tag_list, ",")[[1]][1], single_tag))
```

Expected output (** added for emphasis) :

```
  doc_id          tag_list single_tag
1      A tagA1,tagA2,tagA3      tagA2
2      B       tagB1,tabB2      **tagB1**
3      C      tagC3, tagC4       tagC
4      D tagD1,tagD3,tagD4      **tagD1**
```

Actual output (** added for emphasis):

```
  doc_id          tag_list single_tag
1      A tagA1,tagA2,tagA3      tagA2
2      B       tagB1,tabB2      **tagA1**
3      C      tagC3, tagC4       tagC
4      D tagD1,tagD3,tagD4      **tagA1**
```

I also tried this with modify_if

```
df <- df %>% mutate(single_tag = modify_if(.,is.na(single_tag), ~ str_split(tag_list, ",")[[1]][1], .else=single_tag))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `single_tag = modify_if(...)`.
Caused by error in `where_if()`:
! length(.p) == length(.x) is not TRUE
```

I did some digging and found that the length of .x is 3 and of the predicate .p is 4. I have discovered that .p produces a vector of four logical values one for each row in df. .x I presume is only getting the values of the three columns in one row.

While I know *some way* to achieve what I need, I need to understand what is going on these two cases. I feel like I'm using a traditional way of thinking of how functions and arguments work but somehow it's different in this case (because of vectorisation perhaps?). I tried reading up the documentation and the code but I am stumped.

I'm on R version 4.2.3 if that matters.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Using `mutate()`, functions are applied to the entire column at a time. The transformation does not happen row-by-row (that's less efficient). So when you do `str_split(tag_list, ",")[[1]]` you are basically locking in the first result for the entire column. You need to think in terms of vectorized function: if you pass in a vector of `n` eleents, the function should return `n` values. You can bypass this behavior with `rowwise()` but usually this just makes things more inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through your examples in order:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(single_tag = ifelse(is.na(single_tag), str_split(tag_list, ",")[[1]][1], single_tag))
```

With this, it's instructive to look at the output of str_split(tag_list, ","):

```
str_split(df$tag_list, ",")
[[1]]
[1] "tagA1" "tagA2" "tagA3"

[[2]]
[1] "tagB1" "tabB2"

[[3]]
[1] "tagC3"  " tagC4"

[[4]]
[1] "tagD1" "tagD3" "tagD4"
```

As you can see, getting the first element of the first list is akin to getting the first thing in the first row of the dataframe, hence your result.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(single_tag = modify_if(.,is.na(single_tag), tag_list, .else=single_tag))
```

The issue with this is that `.x` (the first input of the `modify_if`), is, per [the documentation](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/modify.html#arguments), meant to be a vector, but you're passing a dataframe as the first input.

#### Solutions

Update : new solution by [Ritchie Sacramento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77199242/what-gets-passed-to-the-mutate-and-modify/77199273?noredirect=1#comment136095780_77199273) - use `str_split_i()`:

```
df |> mutate(single_tag = ifelse(is.na(single_tag), str_split_i(tag_list, ",", 1), single_tag))
```

Original:

1. Use [`str_extract()`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_extract.html) to get everything before the first comma (`^` is the start, `.` is any character, `*` means match it any number of times, `?` makes sure it is not greedy (i.e. it doesn't just match the whole string if it doesn't have to), `(?=,)` is a look ahead for a comma)

```
df |> mutate(single_tag = ifelse(is.na(single_tag), tag_list, str_extract(tag_list, "^.*?(?=,)")))
```

2. split the `tag_list` column into an *actual* list column, then take the first element of that (using [`map()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html)):

```
df |> mutate(tag_list = str_split(tag_list, ","),
             single_tag = ifelse(is.na(single_tag), map_chr(tag_list, 1), single_tag))
```

3. Use [`map2()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html):

```
df |> mutate(single_tag = map2_chr(tag_list, single_tag, \(t, s) ifelse(is.na(s), str_split(t, ",")[[1]], s)))
```

Comment: re: str_split() that makes so much sense now geez, I feel stupid! Thanks a lot. 
re: modify_if(), does the whole dataframe gets passed as the input? Also, for the sake of my understanding, is there a way to make this code work with modify_if or is it simply not a fit in this case?

Comment: `is there a way to make this code work with modify_if` <- I think it could potentially work with `modify2()` - let me see

Comment: The issue with using `modify_if()` is that you're actually looping over two different things- the tag_list column, and the single_tag  too. So I can do `df |> mutate(new = modify_if(tag_list, is.na(single_tag), ~ str_split(.x, ",")[[1]][1]))`, but it is modifying the wrong column

Comment: you *could* potentially pass both columns as a list, and then decide between them, but it's easier to use `modify2()`, and pass two columns

Comment: @Akhil also clarification - using `.` as the first input of something usually makes it use the input of the pipe it is within, hence you passing the dataframe as input

Comment: @Akhil the `modify2()` version is similar to the `map2` version: `df |> mutate(single_tag = modify2(tag_list, single_tag, \(t, s) if (is.na(s)) str_split(t, ",")[[1]][1] else s))`

Comment: This is a good use case for `str_split_i()`, which returns a character vector of the ith position from a vector of strings to be split.

Comment: ah great point @RitchieSacramento! I wasn't aware of that one - thanks for the tip! edit: updated! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does this give you what you want? Since you are using `dplyr`, I assume using `stringr` as well is not an issue.

```
df |>
  mutate(
    single_tag = ifelse(is.na(single_tag),
                        stringr::str_extract(tag_list, "[:alnum:]+(?=,)"),
                        single_tag)
  )
```

What `str_extract` does is pull out the first part of a string that matches the regular expression in the second argument.

Comment: Damn, that works! How did this work but my str_split with [[1]][1] not work? Aren't they doing pretty much the same thing? That is what I am confused about.

Comment: Try running `str_split(df$tag_list, ",")` and `str_split(df$tag_list, ",")[[1]]` to see why it's not giving you what you want. If you really wanted to use `str_split()`, you could do something like `purrr::map_chr(str_split(df$tag_list, ","), 1)` instead of `str_split(tag_list, ",")[[1]][1]`.